# Why do I recieve a badge for a down vote when I immediately undid the downvote?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I received the critic badge even after I immediately undid my downvote. Is rhis a bug or is it by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.  The idea is that you do not lose badges once awarded.

For reference, here is the related question at meta.stackoverflow:
[Is the Critic badge awarded prematurely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/is-the-critic-badge-awarded-prematurely)